# Mysql Using a variable within a case statement

Tags: mysql, case

Trying to do something very simple.
Want to Run a SP that checks if one of the arguments is null. If so, store an empty string in a log table, otherwise store the value.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_TestVariable`(
Code1 varchar(255) ,
CodeToTest varchar(255)
)
BEGIN

CASE 
WHEN   CodeToTest IS NULL  THEN
 set @FinalCode = ' '

ELSE  
 set @FinalCode = CodeToTest 

end
-- Now do the insert into the log table
INSERT INTO `TempLogTable` ( strField1, strField2)
VALUES (Code1 , @FinalCode );
```

Comment: ... and what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce all that to a simle query

```
INSERT INTO `TempLogTable` (strField1, strField2)
SELECT Code1, coalesce(CodeToTest, '')
```

and for that I would even drop the procedure and just use the query instead.

Comment: Quick and easy. Works for me. Never knew about that function. Thanks!